# Java - Casting a set

Tags: java, casting

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following code?

```
    Set<String> cmds = *a method call that returns a Set<String>*
    String[] cmdarr = (String[]) cmds.toArray();
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<cmdarr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(cmdarr[i]);
```

It gave the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
at a.jim.Test.main(Test.java:79)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `String[] cmdarr = cmds.toArray(new String[0]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Set`itself doesn't have any type information about its elements available at runtime; the type parameter `<String>` is erased during compilation. So, the `toArray()` method always creates an array of type `Object[]`.

You can pass an array to the method and have the contents of the set copied into it:

```
String[] cmdarr = cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]);
```

The the array you pass in is too small, a new one with the same component type will be created using reflection, but that is not as efficient as passing in one of the correct size.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the [type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) reference.

```
String[] cmdarr = cmds.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of what @erickson said, the parameterized type in the `Set` is simply a compile-time safety check. Once the code is compiled, `Set<String>` actually becomes `Set` of `Objects`.

Casting is a method of achieving greater specificity at runtime. You are getting the compile-time error though because of something called "type erasure" that happens to generic types when they are compiled, as explained in the previous paragraph. Your `cmdarr` reference is actually just a placeholder for an object of type `String[]`. This placeholder can never point to a `Object[]` just like a `Set<List>` placeholder can never point to a `Set<ArrayList>`.

Take a look at the walkthrough about generics in the Java Tutorials. It's a lot to wrap your head around, but invaluable when using the Collections package.

[Java Tutorials: Lesson Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)